# Select Customer ID with Condition From Customer Table and Count all log placed using Log table- SQL

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I have two table as defined below,

Table: Customer:

```
   ID       | Customer_Name |Sex (bit)
 --------------------------
    1       | John        | men
    2       | Mack        |women
    3       | Andy        |women
```

Table: Log:

```
   ID      | Customer_ID| Date
 --------------------------
    1      | 1        | 2020-06-03
    2      | 3        |2020-06-03
```

I want to write a query to select each name with Sex condition and count of all Log placed by each customer using JOIN. the result will be,

```
1 |  1
2 |  0
3 |  0
```

My query:

```
(SELECT Customer.ID,  COUNT(Log.Customer_ID) as number 
 from 
 Customer
  Left JOIN 
   Log
     on 
      Customer.Sex=0 and
       Customer.ID=Log.Customer_ID
        and  
        Log.Date>='2020-06-13' 
        group by Customer.ID)
```

But its returning incorrect results. Please advise

Comment: Is the date a string or a datetime?  Putting single quotes around a date make it a string.  I think you may need CAST('2020-06-13' AS datetime)

Comment: date is DateTime but its not problem idont filter out Sex of Custumer

Comment: Always test queries in SQL Server Management Studio before trying in c#.  the error messages are better in SSMS.  Any query that runs in SSMS will also run in c# using SQLClient class, provided the parameter types are the same and the default database is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT Customer.ID,  COUNT(case Customer.Sex when 0 then Log.Customer_ID end) as number 
 from 
 Customer
  Left JOIN 
   Log
     on 
       Customer.ID=Log.Customer_ID
        and  
        Log.Date>='2020-06-13' 
        group by Customer.ID
```

If you need only men/women move the predicate to `WHERE`

```
select Customer.ID, COUNT(Log.Customer_ID) as number 
from Customer
left join Log
     on Customer.ID=Log.Customer_ID
        and Log.Date>='2020-06-13'
where Customer.Sex = 0 
group by Customer.ID
```

Comment: thanks for help ... but i dont filter out sex im this...its return all of Custumers

Comment: @SoroshFt, your required output example lists all 3 customers. Please correct the question if it's wrong.

Comment: I need my output just female or men  with log even count of log is 0 . But this output is all of custumer

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the results this query is returning?

I think left join isn't a good approach, I would try with inner join instead if you want to filter in on clause (or just use where).

```
(SELECT Customer.ID,  COUNT(Log.Customer_ID) as number 
from Customer
JOIN Log on Customer.Sex=0 and Customer.ID=Log.Customer_ID and Log.Date>='2020-06-13' 
group by Customer.ID)
```

Comment: The left join is needed so that you don't filter out the female records.